# Setting bootstrap selectpicker default value in Knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have the following [code](http://jsbin.com/ciged/1/edit?html,js,output), bootstrap-selectpicker wrapped in a custom binding. I am trying to populate a list of various mail providers. I renders properly but I cannot set a value. Notice my code `this.selectedEmailProvider = ko.observable('MAILCHIMP');`, It should set `MAILCHIMP` as the selected item.

Might it be a problem with my custom binding?

```
/**
* Selectpicker binding
* @type {Object}
*/
ko.bindingHandlers.selectPicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        if ($(element).is('select')) {
            if (ko.isObservable(valueAccessor())) {
                ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);
            }
            $(element).selectpicker().addClass('form-control');
        }
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        if ($(element).is('select')) {
            var selectPickerOptions = allBindingsAccessor().selectPickerOptions;
            if (typeof selectPickerOptions !== 'undefined' && selectPickerOptions !== null) {
                var options = selectPickerOptions.options,
                    optionsText = selectPickerOptions.optionsText,
                    optionsValue = selectPickerOptions.optionsValue,
                    optionsCaption = selectPickerOptions.optionsCaption;
                if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options).length > 0) {
                    ko.bindingHandlers.options.update(element, options, ko.observable({
                        optionsText: optionsText,
                        optionsValue: optionsValue,
                        optionsCaption: optionsCaption
                    }));
                }
            }
            if (ko.isObservable(valueAccessor())) {
                ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor);
            }

            $(element).selectpicker('refresh');
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Kindly let me know if you see any issue with this implementation I have tried http://jsbin.com/ciged/2/edit. Note this line: 


var value = allBindingsAccessor.get('value');
if (typeof value !== 'undefined') {
     $(element).selectpicker('val', value());
}